# matplotlib use rgba color for text

Tags: matplotlib, text

I would like to add a text with rgba color but matplotlib rejects it, this is my minimal working example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(0.5,0.5,'wololo', color=np.array([[1,1,1,1]]))
plt.show()
```

it produces the error

```
TypeError: unhashble type: 'numpy.narray'
```

Somehow, it works with string defined colors (see the following example), but I would like it to work with any RGBA format

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(0.5,0.5,'wololo', color='r')
plt.show()
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the array you provide is a 2D array. But RGBA colors should be a 1D array or list. You may use

```
color=np.array([1,1,1,1])            # Use 1D array
```

or

```
color=np.array([[1,1,1,1]]).flat   # flatten 2D array
```

Comment: omg I see, I got confused, as the scatter plot method asks for 2-d np.arrays.
Thank you!